# What's the ‘main’ verb in “I like to start my day with a cup of tea”?

Tags: present-tense

What’s the ‘main’ verb in this sentence and why?

> I like to start my day with a cup of tea.

Is it *like* or is it *start*? Is *to start* really even a verb at all here?

If one of these two verbs is the ‘main’ verb, then what kind of verb is the other one?

How can one clause have two verbs like this?

Comment: Yes, _start_ is a verb, an infinitive (note the _to_); only verbs can be infinitives. However, it's not the main verb; infinitives are always in subordinate clauses. Main verbs have to be inflected, and lexical (present or past tense, and not an auxiliary). So it's _like_, present tense, with the infinitive clause _to start ..._ as its direct object.

Comment: I'd prefer to think of "like" as being the matrix verb, the head of the matrix clause, which here is the entire sentence. Incidentally, under the catenative-auxiliary analysis, every verb is a so-called 'main' verb.

Comment: Yes, but not everybody prefers to think of things the same way.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Yes, *start* is a verb, an infinitive (note the *to*); only verbs can be infinitives. However, it's not the main verb; infinitives are always in subordinate clauses. Main verbs have to be inflected, and lexical (present or past tense, and not an auxiliary). So it's *like*, present tense, with the infinitive clause *to start ...* as its direct object.

Comment: I was just thinking: the Stack Exchange is a great big drag. But then along came something to make me click that up-arrow for all the bubkis it's worth.